# No image from glide in Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm aware that people have had this problem before and there are solutions using Firebase Realtime Database, but I'm using Cloud Firestore and I'm trying to fix this. I do not want do downgrade my dependencies as that isn't a solution. But this is how I save my download url:

```
final String download_uri = uploadTask.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

And this is how I try to populate it to Glide:

```
Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(user_image).into(profilePicture);
```

In firestore, `user_image` has the value `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@d1a2c07`

How do I fix this for firestore?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database, but with how you retrieve the download URL from Firebase Storage. `getDownloadUrl()` nowadays returns a `Task`, so you need to add a listener to that task to wait for its result. The answer by Krishna shows how to do that, but so do many previous questions from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D%5Bandroid%5D+getdownloadurl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `user_image` takes string representation of `Task<Uri>` object,

Here's how you can get download url from Cloud Firestore

```
uploadTask.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
         String url = String.valueOf(task.getResult()));//gives image or file string url
    }
});
```